# Get Friends' Facebook posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to use facebook's FQL to fetch all posts (or video posts) of a user's friend?

For example something like:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id=(fb_friends_array)
```

And how do i use this with the graph api. Normally i use the following syntax to get data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(....));
```

Comment: regarding how to retrieve the data - there are many ways to do so... Your method is just one - but yes... the response you get is in JSON format... taken from [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) : `All responses are JSON objects.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is!

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{friends_uid}/posts
```

This call will return ALL posts ( and data within the posts - comments, etc...) that you have permissions to see( depends on your friends privacy settings )...

In order to retrieve pictures or videos, all you have to do is change "posts" with videos or pictures... Of course your application will have to have permissions to see you friends pictures and videos..

Comment: I know, i did that but how do use one query to get ALL the posts of ALL my friend at once? This gets me only the posts from one friend right? If i use a foreach loop with this query to get all the posts from all my friends it takes around 1 minute...

Comment: you could look into [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) but in anycase you are talking about a relatively large amount of data... collecting it might take time. 
If you are wanting to display these posts to the user you might want to think about using some sort of pagination and load smaller chunks of the data as you need it.  You can base queries on timestamps too so possibly load them in chronological order...